# putting in a loop and how to repeat

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I've just started learning and I've only learnt the basics but this is my current code. I need to put it in a loop and ask the user to place the number for up to 8 times.

```
num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5',]
import random
num = random.choice(num_list)

table = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

ss = {"W1":[0,0],
                "W2":[1,0],
                "W3":[2,0],
                "W4":[3,0],
                "X1":[0,1],
                "X2":[1,1],
                "X3":[2,1],
                "X4":[3,1],
                "Y1":[0,2],
                "Y2":[1,2],
                "Y3":[2,2],
                "Y4":[3,2],
                "Z1":[0,3],
                "Z2":[1,3],
                "Z3":[2,3],
                "Z4":[3,3]}



ans = input('where would you like to place it: ')

index_ = ss[ans][0]
columns_ = ss[ans][1]
table[index_][columns_] = num
print(table)
```

This code below here is supposed to make sure the user is placing the number adjacent to another number.
How do I make sure it only starts to check on the 2nd turn onwards? And how do I get it to repeat the turn if it is not adjacent? I also wanted to put the code above into functions and call it at the end to make it neater but I'm not sure what to put in and what to not.

```
def moveandclip(n, x, y):
   n[0] = max(0, min(n[0] + x, 3))
   n[1] = max(0, min(n[1] + y, 3))
   return n

above = moveandclip(ss[ans], 0 ,1)
below = moveandclip(ss[ans], 0 ,-1)
left = moveandclip(ss[ans], -1 ,0)
right = moveandclip(ss[ans], 1 ,0)

if above == '' and below == '' and left == '' and right == '':
    print('It must be placed adjacent to another number.')
    repeat the turn
else:
    continue to next turn
```

Comment: You can just put the last line of the code (from input) in a loop using for i in range(8)

Comment: You can use `for turn in range(8):` to iterate 8 times. You can check whether `turn > 0` to tell if it's the 2nd turn onward.

Comment: After I use that to iterate it 8 times do I put another loop inside? as in for turn > 1, then I insert my if statement?

Comment: @cherrynote, I have added an answer. You may refer to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the code 8 times, you can do like this:

```
    def moveandclip(n, x, y):
       n[0] = max(0, min(n[0] + x, 3))
       n[1] = max(0, min(n[1] + y, 3))
       return n
    
    above = moveandclip(ss[ans], 0 ,1)
    below = moveandclip(ss[ans], 0 ,-1)
    left = moveandclip(ss[ans], -1 ,0)
    right = moveandclip(ss[ans], 1 ,0)
    
    for _ in range(8):
        if above == '' and below == '' and left == '' and right == '':
            print('It must be placed adjacent to another number.')
        else:
            # Do whatever you want to

        # Add more code if you want to run some more statements regardless of the condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    # Turn code
    if above == '' and below == '' and left == '' and right == '':
        print('It must be placed adjacent to another number.')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: This solution does indeed works but i guess the user wants to print that statement when the user gives the wrong input. Your code will run but break before 8 times if the user gives a wrong input

Comment: Thank you! can I ask for example, on the 4th turn, in the while true portion, after it prints my statement, is it able to go back to 4th turn or does it go on to the 5th?

Comment: @cherrynote, if you want to continue executing statements, you can add them after if and else part, then it will be executed regardless of the condition

Comment: Its my pleasure :)